# Crear un solo array con todos los datos insertados

Tags: array, bucles, prompt

Estoy haciendo un bucle que me pida datos y que cuando pulse cancelar me muestre un único array con todos los datos insertados.
El problema que tengo es que me crea un array por cada palabra que pongo .

Este es el código

```
while(true){
let pedir = prompt('escribe una letra')
if (pedir===null ) break;
let arr= [];
arr.push(pedir);
console.log(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes inicializar la variable de matriz `arr` fuera del bucle, así:

```
let arr= [];
while(true){
  let pedir = prompt('escribe una letra')
  if (pedir===null ) break;
  arr.push(pedir);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

**Explicación:**

Si empiezas el bucle con `while`, luego inicializas la variable `arr` , después le agregas un elemento con `push` y acabas mostrando su contenido con `log` lo que obtienes es solo lo almacenado en ese ciclo.

Cuando se *inicializa* una variable pierde todo el valor anterior, si lo tuviera.

Por lo tanto es lógico que solo muestre un valor, tal como te está sucediendo.  Si la inicializas fuera del bucle y le vas agregando elementos en cada ciclo los conservará todos y se iran mostrando en `log`.